# How to resize margin when window get bigger in javaFX 8?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I know about binding but the problem is you can only bind on pane.prefWidth. What I need is the same thing but for the margin.
My project is a board game. So imagine a scene with 2 gridpane in a borderpane. One is borderpane.setRight and the other in the center. I want all of the space around the gridview to be able to resize itself without moving or resizing the gridPanes.
Sorry that might be a stupid question but it's my first JavaFX project. I've tried to research this but I guess I'm not looking in the right direction..